# socket_bind() unable to bind address

Tags: php, linux, webserver, websocket

I'm trying to create a Web Socket Server for a small project I am working on.

I have set up the server (located at home) and have port forwarded 80 and 22. I read this tutorial: [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)

And whenever I ssh into my server to run "startDarmon.php" I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in  
/var/www/server/socket.class.php on line 48
2013-02-23 14:15:38 System: Socket bound to localhost:8000.
2013-02-23 14:15:38 System: Start listening on Socket
```

This is what i think is preventing my client from connecting to the server. So in the startDarmon.php file I have:

```
$WebSocket = new socketWebSocket('MY_IP_NOT_LAN_IP',8000);
```

And inside my client file, I have:

```
var host = "ws://MY_IP_NOT_LAN:8000/server/startDaemon.php";
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to why this is not allowing me to establish a connection?

Comment: From what I know you don't need this `server/startDaemon.php`

Comment: @Dharman How do you mean? How would the server start then? Because in the client, `var socket = new WebSocket(host)` still requires a host]

Comment: `ws://MY_IP_NOT_LAN:8000` that is just enough to get connection. However this does not solve you problem, its server side based

Comment: Try running it on a different port(you need to do port forward on you rrouter)

Comment: @Dharman I've ran it on a different port, and, it now works. "Socket bound to localhost:3132", "Start listening on Socket." When I enter my client, however, it doesn't want to connect.. Just hangs.. But I haven't forwarded port 3132 to my server (LAN IP) so would this be a good idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is on the Linux server.

Run the `netstat -a -p -n` command under root (e.g. with `sudo`) to understand which process is using that port. Then perhaps do a [setsockopt(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) with `SO_REUSEADDR`
(see [socket(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) for more).

The TCP protocol has some specified delays in minutes (eg keepalive, etc etc...). See e.g. [tcp(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html)

I do suggest reading a good book on Linux system programming like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and perhaps some material on network programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse an address using the setting below:

```
if ( ! socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) 
{ 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
    exit; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another application is already using the port that you are trying to use.You can run

```
lsof -i:port_no
```

to make the port free.